# Formatting multiple columns in dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, formatting

I've multiple columns to format as a float decimal with fixed precision. However, doing with multiple columns at the same time doesn't work. Working on individual columns works. What is the reason and how to resolve the same?

The following works.

```
def shortenlength(numberToShorten):
    limited_float = "{:.15f}".format(numberToShorten)
    return limited_float


outputData['col1'] = outputData['col1'].apply(shortenlength)
outputData['col2'] = outputData['col2'].apply(shortenlength)
```

However, the following doesn't work and throws the error
**TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.**format****

```
def shortenlength(numberToShorten):
    limited_float = "{:.15f}".format(numberToShorten)
    return limited_float

zfill_cols = ['col1', 'col2']
outputData[zfill_cols] = outputData[zfill_cols].apply(shortenlength)
```

Comment: How about `outputData['col1', 'col2'] = outputData[['col1', 'col2']].apply(shortenlength)`?

Comment: Shows the same error ' unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `apply` on a dataframe, the argument passed to the function is the columns, i.e. the series. Use `applymap` instead:

```
outputData[zfill_cols] = outputData[zfill_cols].applymap(shortenlength)
```

Comment: Thanks. Works well.